# Read from executable and write back response

Tags: bash, stdout, stdin

I'm starting an executable with

```
./test
```

It will then write a text to stdout

```
static test: DYNAMIC_VAL
```

The `static test` is always the same but the value `DYNAMIC_VAL` changes.
I need to read `DYNAMIC_VAL`, process it and send back byte hex codes `\x12\x34\x56` to the stdin depending on `DYNAMIC_VAL`.

`./test` is an executable and the stdin should be performed to the original invocation of `test`, otherwise the `DYNAMIC_VAL` would have changed with a new invocation.

Is there a simple way of doing this in `bash`?

Comment: to the stdin of test?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know how to read the output of a command in bash? Do you know how to send "hex codes" back to "the stdin"?

Comment: @OznOg yes to the stdin of test

Comment: @KamilCuk I know that I can normally pipe hex codes with `echo -e "\x12\x34\x45" | ./test"` but in my case I have to read the output first

Comment: are you looking to feed stdout as stdin to the same invocation of `test` or are you looking to invoke a new copy of `test` each time you have a new set of 'byte hex codes' to process?  what is `test`? a binary? a shell script? if a shell script (or you have the source for the binary) then can you edit to do the extra processing inside of `test`? (trying to get a better understanding of the requirements and available options)

Comment: It should be the same invocation of test, otherwise when starting a new invocation the stdout of `DYNAMIC_VAL` will have changed; `test` is a binary; I don't have the source code available

Comment: how to keep this from repeating indefinitely, or will `test` stop generating `static test` output at some point?

Comment: It's just a one time thing, first read the `static test`, process it and write something back to stdin

Comment: what is the origin of DYNAMIC_VAL? why can't you just store it in variable?

Comment: Because it is aprt of the hex values that are being sent back to stdin

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this question correctly, you want to read a line from your `./test` process, and write data back to the same process and repeat until it produces something saying it's done (Or forever)?

One way is to use a [coprocess](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Coprocesses.html).

Example:

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/sh

echo "static test: foo"
read line
echo "static test: bar"
read line
echo "static test: done"

$ cat demo.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

coproc ./test.sh
while true; do
    read -r -u "${COPROC[0]}" s t dynamic_val
    case "$dynamic_val" in
        "done")
            echo "Exiting"
            break;;
        *)
            echo "read $dynamic_val"
            printf "\x12\x34\x56\n" >&"${COPROC[1]}";;
    esac
done

$ ./demo.sh
read foo
read bar
Exiting
```